# Is there any way in SQL Server Management Studio to select multiple lines?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If I control F for a certain keyword like "master" in SQL SSMS it selects that word across multiple different lines. Is there a way for me to highlight the full line wherever there is a match? (So I can do things like cut or copy all the lines that have "master" in it)

I can bookmark all the lines with the Find and replace window now is there any way to select all bookmarked lines?

Comment: Ctrl+F doesn't highlight the words in the same sense as when you use your mouse/cursor. Using Ctrl+F {type word/phrase} Ctrl+C won't copy multiple instances of {word/phrase}. Highlighting and finding text in SSMS is completely different functionality.

Comment: You (or someone who isn't a beginner like me) could probably do this with regex . CTRL + SHIFT + Arrow keys may help you also.